# How to add blank record after last record in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a problem with add new blank record after last record in Crystal Report. That blank record should line like below picture in red box.
[image: Sample Invoice]

I want to show row and column in that blank record as in picture.

Comment: Add data in sub-report and add in main report, and then show one section after that section (which has sub-reports). Let me know in case you need further help.

Comment: can you show me step by step in screenshot or video tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

follow below process

Craete 6 sections in main report and in first section palce the sub report that prints table

In sub report just display table as per your logic and supress remaining sections taht are not used

In main report in blank sections create a similar table structure that you can do by playing with boxes and lines

And finally run the report

Comment: í'm not understand. can you show me video tutorial or screenshot ?

Comment: I don't have a video tutorial... you can just check creating sections and creating sub rpeorts tutorials

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to Statically create that line after the detail section ( in report footer) 
for Ex. you can stretch the lines down in to report footer section and add extra rows there.